# Fill native app with TYPO3 contents

Tags: api, typo3

I have a TYPO3 system and I want to fill native apps (iOS, Android) with content from this CMS.

I googled for TYPO3 API docs but I couldn't find a single client-side example.

All links [like this](http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/CoreApiReference/singlehtml/) just seem to explain the general functionaliy of TYPO 3 and not features for a (REST?) API.

Any ideas how this works or where I can find a first approach?

Thanks,
Ronny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create custom extension which will return API data, on page and/or type serving it you need to disable all headers and allow your plugin to generate raw JSON

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm currently only in charge of doing the client-side. So can I expect the API to work as simple as any regular REST api would work like?

Comment: Yes that's possible to use TYPO3 for REST APIs, anyway I have no sure about support for `PUT`, `DELETE` request methods at the moment. For single `GET` (for delivering data to your aps) you can use TYPO3 with some tweaks

Comment: Cool, for now I just need `GET`. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Here´s an example for connect a TYPO3 Extension with a native iOS app
[Connect TYPO3 Extbase extension with native iOS App(Xcode)](https://github.com/de-velopment/Connect_Webservice_TYPO3_with_native_iOS_App)

Comment: While the link might be helpful, please provide a summary, examples and more, so the answer stays relevant even if the link does not work anymore. Merely posting a link is not a sufficient answer.